# Flutter A RenderFlex overflowed by 99469 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and trying to solve the below issue, in the first screenshot I have labelStart line 127 value as 1.21, when i pass that value using the variable i get renderflex error, if i am using hardcoded i don't get any error. Not sure what i am doing wrong. I tried adding Expanded after reading few posts online but that didn't help. Can someone please guide me on what mistake i am doing here?

```
class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<MusicModel> _list;
  var _value;
  int _playId;
  String _playURL;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  String _startTime;
  String _endTime;
  AnimationController _controller;
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _playId = 0;    
    _list = MusicModel.list;   
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(microseconds: 250));
    _value = 0.0; 
    _startTime="0.0";
    _endTime="0.0";
    super.initState();   
    _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration duration) {
      setState(() {
        _startTime = duration.toString().split(".")[0];
      });
    });
    _audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration duration) {
      setState(() {
        _endTime = duration.toString().split(".")[0];
      });
    });


  }  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Skin - Flume", 
        style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.styleColor),),
      ),

      backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomButtonWidget(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: AppColors.styleColor,                        
                      ),
                      size: 50,
                      onTap: (){

                      },
                    ),
                    CustomButtonWidget(                      
                      image: 'assets/logo.jpg',
                      size: 100,
                      borderWidth: 5,
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DetailPage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    CustomButtonWidget(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        color: AppColors.styleColor,                        
                      ),
                      size: 50,
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )  
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              //Progress bar section
              // Expanded(child: SizedBox()),

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                child: CustomProgressWidget(
                  value: _value,
                  labelStart: "1.21",
                  labelend: "2.34",
                ),
              ),
              // Expanded(child: SizedBox()),


              Expanded( //This is added so we can see overlay else this will be over button

                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),//This line removes the dark flash when you are at the begining or end of list menu. Just uncomment for
                    itemCount: _list.length,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DetailPage(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          //This below code will change the color of sected area or song being played.
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: _list[index].id ==  _playId
                                  ? AppColors.activeColor
                                  : AppColors.mainColor,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                          ),
                          //End of row color change
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16), //This will all padding around all size
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, //This will allign button to left, else button will be infront of name
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                        _list[index].title,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.styleColor,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    Text(
                                        _list[index].album,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.styleColor.withAlpha(90),
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                CustomButtonWidget( //This is Play button functionality on list page. 
                                  child: Icon(
                                    _list[index].id == _playId
                                      ? Icons.pause
                                      : Icons.play_arrow,
                                    color: _list[index].id == _playId
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : AppColors.styleColor,
                                    ),
                                  size: 50,
                                  isActive: _list[index].id == _playId,
                                  onTap: () async {                                       
                                    if (isPlaying){                                       
                                      if (_playId == _list[index].id){                                        
                                        int status = await _audioPlayer.pause();
                                        if (status == 1){
                                          setState(() {
                                            isPlaying = false;
                                          }); 
                                        }
                                      } else {
                                        _playId = _list[index].id;
                                        _playURL = _list[index].songURL;
                                        _audioPlayer.stop();  
                                        int status = await _audioPlayer.play(_playURL);
                                        if (status == 1){
                                          setState(() {
                                            isPlaying = true;
                                          }); 
                                        } 
                                      }
                                      //  int status = await _audioPlayer.pause();
                                      //   if (status == 1){
                                      //     setState(() {
                                      //       isPlaying = false;
                                      //     }); 
                                      //   } 
                                    }  else {
                                      _playId = _list[index].id;
                                      _playURL = _list[index].songURL;
                                       int status = await _audioPlayer.play(_playURL);
                                        if (status == 1){
                                          setState(() {
                                            isPlaying = true;
                                          }); 
                                        } 
                                    } // String filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath();            

                                  },
                                  // onTap: (){
                                  //   setState(() {
                                  //     _playId = _list[index].id;                                      
                                  //   });
                                  // },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),  
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
              )
            ],        
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    AppColors.mainColor.withAlpha(0),
                    AppColors.mainColor,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                )
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

[image]

After changing line 1.27 with a dynamic value variable.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code in your question. Copy-paste the code and error into your question.

Comment: You might be passing `int` value to `labelStart` attribute. It expects a `String` value.

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper no it is expecting string and i am passing a string.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks but as code would have not able to give exact difference, i posted image. I got your point though, it just i felt based on error, image might be more helpful.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to build

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper I am trying to build progress bar, and want pass start and end time to Progress bar Widget. With hardcoded values my UI looks good it fails when i assign variable to widget. Both have same values..

Comment: Seems you are using listview.builder in column

Comment: Can you please sahre the full code??

Comment: I just switched to one package available on pub.dev as i couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Actually GetX is an amazing package. But, not sure why this error creeps up! I am too trying to solve this issue. Any luck so far?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap you Column in a scrollview like `SingleChildScrollView` or `ListView`. This error occurs when the items in column take more space than available.

Comment: ListView Works For me !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my problem was my variable extracted of my state it took too long in show and showed first the widget after the variable.

In my case use Getx, and fixed for this way:

My old code:

```
GetX<UserController>(
          builder: (_){
               
              return Text(_.user.name);

            }
          },
        ),
```

My new code

```
GetX<UserController>(
          builder: (_){
            
            if(_.user.email != null){
              return Text(_.user.name);

            }else{
              return Text('Loading....');
            }
          },
        ),
```